# NetBeans - shortcut for returning to previous position after invoking 'Go to Declaration'

Tags: java, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

In Netbeans I want to be able too return back to my previous position after selecting `Go to Declaration` (`ctrl + click` on variable). Similar to the option in Microsoft Visual Studio .Net IDE when I click (`ctrl + -`) - it will return to the previous position I was in.

Answer (score 89):

Tested, for the 7.1.1 version, it is ALT+LEFT.

Comment: What did you mean by LEFT?

Comment: LEFT= LEFT ARROW KEY <-

Comment: Navigate back (ALT+LEFT) Navigate forward(ALT+RIGHT)

Comment: It's not possible to drag buttons for that into the toolbars, right!?

Comment: Working on my Netbeans 8.2, Windows 7

Answer (score 30):

Another useful shortcut is `ctrl-q` which takes you to the last edit point.

Answer (score 26):

Navigate back :**(ALT+LEFT)**

Navigate forward :**(ALT+RIGHT)**

Comment: And on OS X? ALT+LEFT is cursor jumping words.

Answer (score 6):

For El Capitan one needs to go to the System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and under "Mission Control" disable the ctrl-arrow sequences and then it works

Comment: Just to add, for me it worked in HighSierra (10.13) with Netbeans 8.2 :D

Answer (score 3):

For **El Capitan** I was not able to figure this out.

So instead I applied my own keybinding.

Go to *Netbeans -> preferences -> keymap*

Search for "back" and add your own keybinding.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Alt-K`

In the menu this is `Navigate --> Back`

Comment: thank you yes it is from menu Navigate-> back in NetBeans 7 shortcut  is (alt + left)

Answer (score 0):

Tested for Netbeans 8.2 on MAC, it is ctrl+B.

Answer (score -6):

I think you should try:
**Control + W**

**Command + W** on MAC

Comment: This closes the window. `</funpolice>`

Comment: It closes the current window but takes you back to the previous window where you are coming from

Comment: cmd + w works for me (Mac) - no matter this is system shortcut for closing windows.